# Is there a list of the most popular (micro)services available for Node.js on Google App Engine?

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine

Is there a list of the most popular (micro)services available for Node.js on Google App Engine?

The tutorials mention Services and how to configure them. For example,
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/deploying-web-service

It would be great to see a list of the most popular services for Node

Answer (score 0):

If you mean frameworks for Node.js, [you can install any of them](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/specifying-dependencies#installing_a_web_framework) by specifying your dependency in your `package.json` file.

This is true for both the Standard environment and the Flexible environment.